# How to replace entries in an array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array, like:

```
key = ['*', '(DATE*', '*', '*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '(GPE*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '(DATE)', '*']
```

I have such an array for which I want to perform task like,

1. run through the array
2. once I find the entry starting with '(' but not ending with ')'
3. replace the next '*' entries until we don't find '*)' and also replace '*)' with the strip of found entry of starting with '('
4. and if the entry is within '()' should be just stripped. as for **2nd last** element (DATE) to be replaced with DATE only

for E.g.
 we have **2nd entry '(DATE*'** followed by '*','*','*)' so these entries should be replaced with DATE only

output should be:

```
key = ['*', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'GPE', 'GPE', '*', '*', '*', 'DATE', '*']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
**Nothing but some regex and while loops**
import re
key = key = ['*', '(DATE*', '*', '*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',
             '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '(GPE*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '(DATE)', '*']
val = 0
while val < len(key):
    value = key[val]
    if re.findall(r'\(',value):
        value = re.findall(r'\w+', value)[0]
        while re.findall(r'\)', key[val]) == []:
            key[val] = value
            val += 1
        key[val] = value
    val += 1
print key
```

output - `['*', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'GPE', 'GPE', '*', '*', '*', 'DATE', '*']`

Answer (score 1):

I know its not much pythonic , anyway you can try this one :

```
key = ['*', '(DATE*', '*', '*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*',
   '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '(GPE*', '*)',
   '*', '*', '*', '(DATE)', '*']

for i in key:
    if i.startswith('(') and not (i.endswith(')')):
        a = key[key.index(i)+1:]
        for j in a:
            if j.endswith(')'):
                a = a[:a.index(j)+1]
                break
        for l in range(key.index(i), key.index(i)+len(a)+1):
            key[l] = i.strip('(').strip('*')
    elif i.startswith('(') and i.endswith(')'):
        key[key.index(i)] = i.strip('(').strip(')')

print(key)
```

It will give **O/P** like :

```
['*', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 
 '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'GPE', 
'GPE', '*', '*', '*', 'DATE', '*']
```

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

```
`key = ['*', '(DATE*', '*', '*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '(GPE*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '(DATE)', '*']
outKeys = []
isFound = False
for k in key:
    if k.startswith("(") and k.endswith(")"):
        k = k[k.find("(")+1:k.find(")")]
    elif k.startswith("("):
        k = k[k.find("(")+1:k.find("*")]
        isFound = k
    elif k.endswith(")"):
        k = isFound
        isFound = False
    elif isFound:
        k = isFound
    outKeys.append(k)
print(outKeys)`
```

This will give u output:

```
['*', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', 'DATE', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', 'GPE', 'GPE', '*', '*', '*', 'DATE', '*']
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this easily readable solution. I defined another list `newKey` to avoid modifying a list while iterating over its owm elements :

```
key = ['*', '(DATE*', '*', '*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '(GPE*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '(DATE)', '*']


newKey = []
next_x = None

for x in key:
    if x.startswith('(') and x.endswith(')'):
        newKey.append(x.strip('()*'))
    elif x.startswith('('):
        newKey.append(x.strip('(*'))
        next_x = x.strip('(*')
    elif x.endswith(')'):
        newKey.append(next_x.strip('*)'))
        next_x = None
    elif next_x is not None:
        newKey.append(next_x)
    else:
        newKey.append(x)  

key = newKey[:]

print(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
current_entry = None
for i, k in enumerate(key):
    if k.startswith('(') and k.endswith(')'):
        key[i] = k.strip('(').strip(')')
        continue
    if k.startswith('(') and not k.endswith(')'):
        current_entry = k.strip('(').strip('*')
    if current_entry:
        key[i] = current_entry
    if k.endswith(')'):
        current_entry = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using a simple regex:

```
string = ' '.join(['*', '(DATE*', '*', '*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*', '(GPE*', '*)', '*', '*', '*', '(DATE)', '*'])
result = re.sub(r'\((.*?)\)', lambda m: ' '.join([m.group(1).replace('*', '').strip()
 for n in range(1 if m.group(0).count('*') == 0 else m.group(0).count('*'))]), string).split(' ')
print(result)
```